# I am tring to connect MySQL db via jdbc but the code is throwing error "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"

Tags: java, mysql, exception, jdbc

Mycode:

```
public class database_connection {

public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {

     Connection conn = null;
      String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
      String dbName = "mycooldatab";
      String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
      String userName = "root"; 
      String password = "root";  

      try{
          Class.forName(driver).newInstance();// create object of Driver
          conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName,userName,password);
          // connection will be established

          // *******************Statement******************
          Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
          ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from student");

        //  rs.next(); // 1st row
        //  System.out.println(rs.getString("name"));


                }  catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
      }finally{
          conn.close();
      }
```

---

error : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

---

I had tried adding the below line to classpath from system environment variables.

"C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\Connector J 5.1.20.0\mysql-connector-java-5.1.20-bin.jar"

but still no good. I am getting same error , can someone figure out and suggest solution, please?

Comment: problem could be spaces in the system path, put driver in a directory like c:\driver\mysql-driver.jar and give tha in classpath

Comment: it is valid point. though my issue resolved. I think i need to modify my classpath. but the directory is just as it is while installing mysql. i havent done any modifications on directory name.

Comment: The classpath currently used depends on how the Java application is executed. E.g. by `java.exe` in command prompt, or as JAR doubleclicked in file explorer, or by *Run* command in an IDE, etc. So, if you elaborate that part in detail, then you will likely get the right answer sooner.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8745872/classnotfoundexception-com-mysql-jdbc-driver) - this has been asked hundreds of times already on SO.

Comment: Setting the system `CLASSPATH` variable almost never works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt your classpath is properly set.

To verify that, add this line at beginning of your `main()`:

```
 System.out.println("CLASSPATH IS=" + System.getProperty("java.class.path"));
```

And verify that the `mysql-connector-java-5.1.20-bin.jar` is properly shown in that line.

Answer (score 0):

sorry, it is mistake from me.

I forgot to add mysql jar file in eclipse that I am using . it is working fine.

Comment: we were all beginners at the beginning! :)