# Error with jdbc mysql connections with jasper server

Tags: java, mysql, jasperserver

I am using jasper server CP 5.0.0. I have configured the data source properties like this

Set Data Source Type and Properties

```
Driver (required):com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
URL (required):jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jasperserver
```

The connection is failed when clicked on *test connection*

When I am running the report I am getting a **error**

```
Error Message

com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.JSExceptionWrapper: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Error Message
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Error Trace

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver at
```

I have been searching this for a long time with no success.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8746015/112500

Comment: exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8745872/classnotfoundexception-com-mysql-jdbc-driver

Answer (score 1):

You should add `mysql drivers jar file` to the `build path` of your project.

Comment: Ok, I restarted the server with adding the jar file now I have the error.com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.JSException: jsexception.error.creating.connection and Error Message

java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'jasperadmin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: this is because you are not providing password in mysql connection, provide username and password with connection string of mysql

Comment: there are so many questions asked for `...(using password: YES)` this error, so i will suggest you to refer to those questions on StackOverflow and if you still can't find solution then  ask separate question for this exception

Comment: Thanks a lot guys.. u saved my day..It's just like 'talaash' the answer lies within..