# Why I keep getting ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver Error on Eclipse IoT

Tags: mysql, eclipse, jdbc, intel-edison, intel-galileo

Im getting started with Eclipse IoT and when trying to create the SQL connector I get the errors bellow. I have added the classpath in windows and the corresponding .jar library is added to the project as advised in [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8745872/classnotfoundexception-com-mysql-jdbc-drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8745872/classnotfoundexception-com-mysql-jdbc-driver). I cannot get why Im still getting this error. Any ideas?

The code that generates the error:

```
public static void getConnection(){
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
            System.out.print(" Class.forName cannot be found");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And I get this:

```
 Class.forName cannot be foundjava.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at controller.establishConnection.getConnection(establishConnection.java:17)
```

Answer (score 0):

if its a web-project: check whether the jar (or the folder which contains the jar) is really in the the `Deployment Assembly` of your project (which is set in the project properties). If not, add it.

Comment: It is not a web project, it is to be run on an Intel Edison board. So Eclipse loads it into the board.